# ExtJs:How to get Session variable

Tags: extjs4

In my Java web application,when a user gets logged in,i store the user name and other details in session as follows,

```
session.setAttribute("userName",username);
```

I am using ExtJs4 for UI.**How to get the  session variables** in extJs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't get session variables off the server web container using javascript only.

I do the same thing (storing userId as a session variable in java). I use `Ext.Request` to perform an Ajax request to a java servlet to get it (along with other data about the user like permission settings for the webapp to enable or disable features they wouldn't be able to use).

**EDIT:**

I second sha's answer also, the only reason I pass the authentication information back to the client is for cosmetic reasons - so that user doesn't think he can use a feature in javascript that would be denied by my server side authentication. If he were to spoof the userId or permissions and try to use the feature, the real authentication on the server side would stop him.

Answer (score 0):

I can second @Geronimo approach. You need to get user Id and/or permissions when you authenticate the user. However...

You can't rely just on the username/permissions that you store somewhere in your JS code because it can't be easily spoofed. If you present user with some information that can be different for different levels of access you still need to do server side validation of the user identity.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question has been asked for a long time ago, but despite the large number of views and the absence of an plain answer, I decided to offer this answer:

Assume that the session variable is registered like /index.php?PHPSESSID=9ebca8bd62c830d3e79272b4f585ff8f

In this case, you can get the variable PHPSESSID through JS object "location" and transform it through Ext.Object.fromQueryString()

So:

```
console.log( Ext.Object.fromQueryString( location.search ) );
```

will prepare PHPSESSID variable for your needs.