# ext JS login session

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

Hi all I'm new in Ext JS. It's my first time to use THIS stuffs. I'm having some problem that how to display session username . can anyone show some example to callback to JS file .

Comment: About session variables a previous question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459124/extjshow-to-get-session-variable

Comment: not help to much ,any simple  tutorial ?

Comment: how get from server side and show username at tbar  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to genetare session username with PHP (server side) and not  javascript

```
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello<?PHP echo $username;?>',
    width: 200,
    html: '------ ',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```